# Mysql taking long for larger limits

Tags: mysql, sql

We have several MySql queries which are performing well when a smaller number of records are selected i.e limit 0,100.

The query taken almost 10X to 50X more time when we increase the limit from 100 to 1000 i.e limit 0,1000.

**EDITED**
How can we optimize this? Explain plan give below,

[image: Explain PLan]

**QUERY**

```
 Select  
   concat(floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,x.msgCreatedOn, NOW())/60),':',floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,x.msgCreatedOn, NOW())%60)) as aging,
   x.`actionStartDate`,  
   concat(floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,x.`actionStartDate`, NOW())/60),':',floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,x.`actionStartDate`, NOW())%60)) as workflowAging 
from 
   (  
    Select 
        * 
    from  
        t_wk_dtls d left 
    join  t_s_dtls s  on  (d.id = s.`work_parentId` or d.`parentId` = s.`work_parentId`) and d.`currentlyActive` = true  
    left join t_w b on b.basketId=d.toBasketId  
    left join t_u u on d.toUserId= u.userId 
    left join t_s_m sch on d.sourceId=sch.schMsgId   
    left join t_l_s_a a on a.orgId='1002'  
            AND ((((a.`type`='TWITTER' and d.channel in (1,34)) 
or (a.`type`='FACEBOOK' and d.channel in (6,7)) 
or (a.`type`='GOOGLEPLUS' and d.channel in (5,25)) 
or (a.`type`='LINKEDIN' and d.channel =30) 
or (a.`type`='GOOGLEPLUS' and d.channel=36) 
or ((a.`type`='YOUTUBE' or a.`type`='GOOGLEPLUS') and d.channel=27) 
or (a.`type`='TUMBLR' and d.channel in (29,31)) 
or (a.`type`='INSTAGRAM' and d.channel=35) ) AND d.userChannelId=a.socialId)              OR (a.`type`='BLOG' and d.channel in (9,11,15,21) AND d.msgId=a.socialId)) 
     left join t_l l on l.leadId=a.leadId and l.orgId='1002' 
where 
     d.currentlyActive = true 
 and d.dataSource ='SOLR'   
 and d.profileId = '148' AND msgCreatedOn BETWEEN '2016-03-14 18:30:00' AND '2016-03-31 18:29:59'  
 order by d.msgCreatedOn desc limit 0,100000 ) as x
```

Comment: Note that much more data is transferred.

Comment: could you add the query to the question? it might be cross join or something else that starts slowing the query down with higher limits.

Comment: Please provide the query and more details. It depends on so many reasons. What indexes you use, what are the filters, are there many text fields and so on.

Comment: @dns_nx  Provided the query and explain plan.

Comment: @jester provided the plan as screen shots and query above.. help appreciated.

Comment: @CoolTechie could you reorganize the query with readable indentation? give me another heads up when you have, also have you made an index for the columns that are being used to filter on?

Comment: @Jester re-organized the query. Yes we have index on the columns.  Just some extra info t_wk_dtls and  t_s_dtls are huge tables.

Comment: what happens if you remove the order by? does that speed it up significantly?

Comment: @jester not significantly, in lesser numbers though there is an improvement.

Comment: I don't know if i am asking the right question, but why would limit change the response so drastically. Isn't limit applied on available results.

Comment: what is the duration for getting 100.000 results? and why would you need to retrieve so many? i can't imagine you're going to generate a table with 100.000 rows? also what types are the indexes? filtering on ints is generally much faster then on strings or dates or others. did you index all the columns filtered on? not just the id's

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107955/discussion-between-cool-techie-and-jester).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really even need a subquery for this? As it is now, notice the "dependant subquery" in the explain results - it generally means that the subquery is executed once per outer row returned (see [point 18.2.1.18.2 in "18.2.1.18 Subquery optimization"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html)). As a result, your execution time grows exponentially as more rows are returned.

Since you're just doing a `select * from` in the subquery, wouldn't something like this accomplish the same?

```
Select 
   concat(floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,x.msgCreatedOn, NOW())/60),':',floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,x.msgCreatedOn, NOW())%60)) as aging,
   x.`actionStartDate`,  
   concat(floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,x.`actionStartDate`, NOW())/60),':',floor(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,x.`actionStartDate`, NOW())%60)) as workflowAging 
from  
    t_wk_dtls d left 
join  t_s_dtls s  on  (d.id = s.`work_parentId` or d.`parentId` = s.`work_parentId`) and d.`currentlyActive` = true  
left join t_w b on b.basketId=d.toBasketId  
left join t_u u on d.toUserId= u.userId 
left join t_s_m sch on d.sourceId=sch.schMsgId   
left join t_l_s_a a on a.orgId='1002'  
        AND ((((a.`type`='TWITTER' and d.channel in (1,34)) 
or (a.`type`='FACEBOOK' and d.channel in (6,7)) 
or (a.`type`='GOOGLEPLUS' and d.channel in (5,25)) 
or (a.`type`='LINKEDIN' and d.channel =30) 
or (a.`type`='GOOGLEPLUS' and d.channel=36) 
or ((a.`type`='YOUTUBE' or a.`type`='GOOGLEPLUS') and d.channel=27) 
or (a.`type`='TUMBLR' and d.channel in (29,31)) 
or (a.`type`='INSTAGRAM' and d.channel=35) ) AND d.userChannelId=a.socialId)     OR (a.`type`='BLOG' and d.channel in (9,11,15,21) AND d.msgId=a.socialId)) 
 left join t_l l on l.leadId=a.leadId and l.orgId='1002' 
where 
 d.currentlyActive = true 
 and d.dataSource ='SOLR'   
 and d.profileId = '148' AND msgCreatedOn BETWEEN '2016-03-14 18:30:00' AND     '2016-03-31 18:29:59'  
 order by d.msgCreatedOn desc limit 0,100000;
```

(except with the table prefixes changed from "x" to the real ones in the column list at the beginning)